# Facebook writing dialog don't show message

Tags: android, facebook

I write an message by facebook dialog after login.
Before write, in Facebook.java, I assign message using this code( parameter.putString("message", "bla bla");)
But as you can see in the picture, the message box is empty.
Previously, the problem was unprecedented.
No change in source. But a few days ago, the problem have occured.
Follwing is FbDialog.java's log(onPageStarted method). Message is not empty.
What is the matter? :)

Comment: I dont see any picture here or FBDialog.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook is now ignoring the message parameter:

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/510/

> message : This field will be ignored on July 12, 2011 The message to
>   prefill the text field that the user will type in. To be compliant
>   with Facebook Platform Policies, your application may only set this
>   field if the user manually generated the content earlier in the
>   workflow. Most applications should not set this.